# Save system information (mdf or app.config)

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config, mdf, local-database

I would like your opinion.

I am creating a WinForm application (C#) and I would like to know if there is any problem using a local database to save the application settings instead of app.config. My system constantly retrieves configuration data to continue processes, but there are not many requests or require data with great information, just to validate whether one configuration or another is activated.

I already use mdf file to generate some filters, I was wondering if there is a problem putting the application settings in it.

My mdf file is 8mb in size, practically the standard when it is created, and will not store much information in it.

Comment: It really doesn't matter. Pick whatever you see comfortable. Just a set of files is enough most of the time for any type of config. Create config catalog and just serialize everything in there.

Comment: A problem it isn't, but there are pros and cons for everything. If you need to change things manually as well, then the config file is more convenient.

Comment: The problem with mdf files is that you need SQL Server installed. That is fine if you need it, but I think it is too much for configuration. SQLite database is lighter and it doesn't require installation, even a bunch of text files might be sufficient as eocron said.